# Shell script to move empty folders into a subfolder

Tags: shell, scripting, directory, mv

I have many empty folders that I do not want to delete but move to a subfolder called "my_empty_folders". How can I do that in a shell script?

Comment: You can use `find` command in combination with `-type` , `-empty` and `-exec` options. Give it a try by yourself.

Comment: I've already tried it myself (look for the question "moving folder older than 30 days to another folder"), unfortunately that's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`:

```
find / -empty -type d -exec mv {} /path/to/my_empty_folders \;
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, empty folders that contain more empty folders are not moved. Example: A folder called "1" contains the empty folders "2", "3" and "4". 2,3,4 are being moved, but folder 1 remains at its original location. I can work around the problem of double executing the command, but I do not want that. Any advice?

Comment: @Karina Folder that contain another folder is not empty! You can write more advanced script and build list of directories to remove

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a shell script, but just a single command.

```
 $ man mv
 $ mv file1 file2 file3 -t <destination/path>
```

For instance, if your directories are called empty_1, empty_2, empty_3, just do

`mv empty* -t <destination/path>`

Comment: And how do you know which directories are empty?

Comment: he/she said she had many different empty directories. So he/she already knows. Why the downvote?